# Powershell Script Organize ACL List 0 hitcnts

Tags: powershell

I have a list of ACLs that I need to organize so I can remove them from another database.  Some of the lines have subnets as the source, some have ip addresses.  Does anyone know anyway I can organize this into a csv file like this:

```
Jerry,192.168.1.2,192.168.1.3
Jason,2.2.2.2,192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
```

```
access-list outside line 1 extended permit tcp object-group Jerry host 10.10.10.1 eq 7030 0x1a9153aa 
  access-list outside line 1 extended permit tcp host 192.168.1.1 host 10.10.10.1 eq 7030 (hitcnt=6) 0x3b6b876b 
  access-list outside line 1 extended permit tcp host 192.168.1.2 host 10.10.10.1 eq 7030 (hitcnt=0) 0x592c1755 
  access-list outside line 1 extended permit tcp host 192.168.1.3 host 10.10.10.1 eq 7030 (hitcnt=0) 0x8cd36041
  access-list outside line 1 extended permit tcp host 192.168.1.4 host 10.10.10.1 eq 7030 (hitcnt=17) 0x8c336546
access-list outside line 2 extended permit tcp object-group Jason host 10.10.10.5 eq 3051 0x4e3c0d1d 
  access-list outside line 2 extended permit tcp host 2.2.2.2 host 10.10.10.5 eq 3051 (hitcnt=0) 0xfeb14ea6 
  access-list outside line 2 extended permit tcp 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 host 10.10.10.5 eq 3051 (hitcnt=0) 0xfafda7ae 
  access-list outside line 2 extended permit tcp host 3.3.3.3 host 10.10.10.5 eq 3051 (hitcnt=10) 0xaed11ed5
```

Comment: What is producing the output in the second snippet? Is the output _text_ or objects?

Comment: It's an output from a Cisco ASA firewall.  I've sanitized the output

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the input is *text* that must therefore be parsed (and that you have no way to request a *structured* text format at the source), you can use a [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) statement:

```bash
& {
  $addresses = $null
  switch -regex ($lines) {
    '(?<= object-group )\w+' { 
      if ($addresses) {
            (, $user + $addresses) -join ','
      }
      $user = $Matches[0] 
      $addresses = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]] @()
      continue
    }
    '(?<= tcp host )\S+' { $addresses.Add($Matches[0]); continue }
    '(?<= tcp )\S+ \S+'  { $addresses.Add($Matches[0]) }
  }
  if ($addresses) {
    (, $user + $addresses) -join ','
  }
}
```

Output with your sample input:

```
Jerry,192.168.1.1,192.168.1.2,192.168.1.3,192.168.1.4
Jason,2.2.2.2,192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0,3.3.3.3
```

Note that if you want to write the resulting lines to a CSV file, you'll have to prepend a *header* row that gives each column a distinct name. For that, you'll at least have to know the maximum number of addresses across all rows, and the rows may have different numbers of fields filled in.

Therefore, a better way to structure your CSV is to normalize it and to write your data as name-address pairs, which also simplifies the code:

```bash
& {
  switch -regex ($lines) {
    '(?<= object-group )\w+' { $user = $Matches[0]; continue }
    '(?<= tcp host )\S+' { [pscustomobject] @{ Name = $user; Address = $Matches[0] }; continue }
    '(?<= tcp )\S+ \S+'  { [pscustomobject] @{ Name = $user; Address = $Matches[0] } }
  }
} | ConvertTo-Csv
```

Output:

```
"Name","Address"
"Jerry","192.168.1.1"
"Jerry","192.168.1.2"
"Jerry","192.168.1.3"
"Jerry","192.168.1.4"
"Jason","2.2.2.2"
"Jason","192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0"
"Jason","3.3.3.3"
```